# save state of texture in file and reopen for editing in OpenGLes2.0 android

Tags: android, opengl-es, save, textures, state

i build a collage app in opengl now i want to save state of all texture on screen in a file, then again open as edit mode like Photo Shop Document file..

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL is a drawing API. It's not a graphics manipulation library (despite what the name suggests). While what you want to do is certainly possible to do, it's not the recommended thing to do.

If you're implementing an image editor you should not rely on OpenGL to hold your data.

Comment: i want only save the state of all texture on screen in a file with its matrix and vertex position and in future i open as it as in edit mode so I add more texture image in it again...

Comment: @user3113932: That's not how OpenGL works. OpenGL is not a scene graph. All it does it rasterizing points, lines or triangles to the screen, applying shaders (which in turn pull in texture data) doing so. *Once OpenGL is finished drawing it completely forgets about what it just did. OpenGL doesn't "remember" vertices, texture coordinates and such.* All that's left behind is a picture. Everything that goes beyond that is *your* responsibility to implement.

Comment: I know its too late.
But i am explaining this for other users,
1. First thing I am using openGL for rendering bitmap in texture, doing manipulation like rotate, zoom and translate for this I am using openGL matrices. I am using OpenGL here basically for creating collage app and editing/effect on a image.
2. I want to save state for saving the state of a collage for re-editng the collage I made.

Comment: Finally I was done using serialization, where i was saved whole matrices, bitmaps, vertices in a file as a object. And retrieve the object and re-create the collage as it was.